# How to do replaceWith() for all future elements with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace, onload, replacewith

I have the following coldes to replace all .replaceclass classes with something else, and it's working fine.

```
$('.replaceclass').replaceWith(function() {
    return 'string to be replaced';
});
```

But now I have some .replaceclass elements that were not generatede on first load, but may be loaded by ajax later, I also want them to get replaced every time when it's loaded.

I tried:

```
$('.replaceclass').on('load', function(){
    $('.replaceclass').replaceWith(function() {
        return 'string to be replaced';
    }); 
});
```

But it's not working. How can I achieve the desired result? Thank you very much!

Comment: Try to do replacement inside your ajax complete callback?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`$.ajaxSuccess`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxsuccess/) which attaches a function to be executed whenever an Ajax request completes successfully.

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function(){
   $('.replaceclass').replaceWith(function() {
      return 'string to be replaced';
   }); 
});
```

This is a global event and gets triggered everytime there is a successful ajax operation. If you don't want a specific ajax call to trigger it, simply add `global: false` in its options.

Answer (score 0):

What about that?

```
$.ajax({
  ......
 }).done(function() {
   replaceClasses();
 });

function replaceClasses(){
  $('.replaceclass').replaceWith(function() {
    return 'string to be replaced';
  }); 
}
```